# Git cherry-pick issue

Tags: git

When I tried to do a git cherry-pick, I received this error

> commit xxx is a merge but no -m option was given.

When I tried to throw in -m, it gives

> error: switch `m' requires a value.

Any idea why this error is happening? There seems to be a merge conflict on Gerrit but it doesn't show any merge conflict locally.

Comment: Cherry-picking and resolving merge conflicts are quite orthogonal from one another.  What issue are you actually trying to resolve?

Comment: The option `-m` needs a value which means the sequence number of the parent commits. You could find more info in `git cherry-pick --help`.

Comment: Rather than attempt to cherry-pick the merge commit, I recommend just cherry-picking the commits that include your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Merge commits have more than one parent and the resulting revision is (theoretically) the mixture of the changes from both parent branches. If you are trying to cherry-pick a merge revision, git wants to know which of the revision parents is the one you would like to consider as it it **were** your current HEAD (so to pull changes from the other parents of the merge revision).